# How to format a price correctly regardless of decimal format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want it to be able to read in  JSON and save it correctly regardless whether the value is `44.5`, `44` or `44.99`. The price attributes are a decimal format.

The error is happening in the `convert_price` method.  The price in the JSON response can be `44`, `44.50` or `44.99`.  However, I noticed that sometimes the last decimal is cut off, like in the error `44.5`.

I'm receiving this error:

```
undefined method 'match' for float 74.5:Float
```

My code is:

```
# read in JSON and create books
def create_item
  job_items_url = "https://foobar.com&format=json"
  response = open(job_items_url).read.to_s
  books = JSON.parse(response)

  Book.create(reg_price: convert_price(item['reg_price']),
    sale_price: convert_price(item['sale_price']))
  end

# format the price
def convert_price(price)
  return nil if price.blank? || price.to_f.zero?
  price = "#{price}.00" unless price.match(/[,.]\d{2}\z/)
  price.delete(',.').to_f / 100
end
```

Comment: You may want to consider using `shopify-money` — it's only going to get more complicated. https://github.com/Shopify/money

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `price` is already a `Numeric` object. Check out `sprintf` for simple Type-aware padding, for example:

```rb
sprintf('%.2f', 44.5) # => "44.50"

# so you should do something like this:
sprintf('%.2f', price.to_f)
```

A suggestion:

```rb
def try_format_currency(price)
  sprintf('%.2f', Float(price))
rescue => ex
  # log error if you want
  nil
end
```

- Use `Float()` conversion, which can raise, which will clearly express that `price` is "untrustworthy" input, and might not be a proper number
- Express the same thing in the naming of the method

Answer (score 1):

You can use `number_to_currency` without a unit:

```
>> number_to_currency(45,unit:"")
=> "45.00"
>> number_to_currency(45.5,unit:"")
=> "45.50"
>> number_to_currency(45.55,unit:"")
=> "45.55"
>>
```

See [`number_to_currency`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_currency) for more information.